# Set a css active class on knockout foreach

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, foreach

I want to set an `active` class on an `li` if the current router title matches the title on the `li` in the `foreach`.

View:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: routes">
    <li><a><span data-bind="text: title, css: {active: isActive }"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Viewmodel:

```
    var self = this;

    self.routes = ko.observableArray(router.navigationModel());

    self.isActive = function(route){
        return router.activeInstruction().config.title === route;
    };
```

This current code doesn't even call the isActive function, but if I make it an observable function for example it calls isActive but the route param is always undefined, even if i try to pass like this:

```
css: {active: isActive(title) }
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? Basically I want the li to add the class or not based on the function check.

UPDATE:

Final working code:

View:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: routes">
    <li data-bind="css: {active: $root.isActive(title) }"><a><span data-bind="text: title"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

ViewModel:

```
    var self = this;

    self.routes = ko.observableArray(router.navigationModel());
    self.current_route = ko.observable(router.activeInstruction().config.title);

    self.isActive = function(route){
        return self.current_route() === route;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, there is nothing in the isActive function which uses the viewModel, therefore the isActive function won't be calculated if anything changes: nothing is going to call function(route).

isActive needs to evaluate something like self.routes() within itself in order to be called whenever self.routes changes, so it becomes

```
 self.isActive = function() {
         var result = foo(self.routes) ; // some calculation on the self.routes array 
         return result;

 }
```

Comment: thanks this led me to the answer. I'll edit my question to show the final code

Comment: glad it helped. Any answer with foo() in it is only a clue :-)